# UIProgressview not changing while downloading files

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

I am making an app where I must download some files from a webserver and save it locally. I have the following `JSON`:

```
{
status: 200,
message: "OK",
files: [
"magazines/dentalasia/DentalAsia1/images/toc-thumb-dummy.jpg",
"magazines/dentalasia/DentalAsia1/images/bg-grid-iphone.png",
"magazines/dentalasia/DentalAsia1/images/cover/toc-thumb.jpg",
"magazines/dentalasia/DentalAsia1/images/cover/cover-typo.png",
...
]
}
```

What I do is I save this string values into an `NSArray` and then I'm going to download each one of them.

```
-(IBAction)downloadMagazine:(id)sender{
    // 1
    progressView.hidden = NO;

    NSArray *splitArray = [mag.mag_folder componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *magName = [splitArray lastObject];

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/webservice/magazine/get-book/apikey/%@/magazine/%@/name/%@",baseUrl,apikey,magazine,magName];
    NSLog(@"STRING IS %@",string);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // 2
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        //Create general directory

        NSDictionary *JSON = [responseObject copy];
        NSArray *files = [JSON valueForKey:@"files"];
        reversedFiles = [[files reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];

        amountFiles = reversedFiles.count;

        NSArray *splitArray = [mag.mag_folder componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
        NSString *magName = [splitArray lastObject];

        NSString *rootString = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:magName];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:rootString])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:rootString withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
        rootString = [rootString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/www"];
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:rootString])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:rootString withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];


        for(int i = 0 ; i<reversedFiles.count ; i++){
            NSString *file = [reversedFiles objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",baseUrl,file];
            NSArray *splitUrl = [file componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
            NSString *lastObject = [splitUrl lastObject];
            if ([lastObject rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound) {
                rootString = nil;
                rootString = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:magName];
                rootString = [rootString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/www"];
                for (int i=0; i<splitUrl.count; i++) {
                    if(i>2){
                        NSString *pathComponent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[splitUrl objectAtIndex:i]];
                        rootString = [rootString stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathComponent];
                    }
                }
                if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:rootString])
                    [self calculatePie:i];
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:rootString withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
            }else{
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];
                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                if(data)
                {
                    rootString = nil;
                    rootString = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:magName];
                    rootString = [rootString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/www"];
                    for (int i=0; i<splitUrl.count; i++) {
                        if(i>2){
                            NSString *pathComponent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[splitUrl objectAtIndex:i]];
                            rootString = [rootString stringByAppendingPathComponent:pathComponent];
                        }
                    }
                    [data writeToFile:rootString atomically:YES];
                    [self calculatePie:i];
                }
            }
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        // 4
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving magazine"
                                                            message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }];
    // 5
    [operation start];
}


-(void)calculatePie:(int)i{
    float progress = (100.0 / amountFiles) * i;
    float progress2 = progress / 100.0;
    NSLog(@"Progress is %f",progress2);
    [progressView setProgress:progress2 animated:YES];

}
```

And this is how a part of my `LOG` looks like:

```
2014-04-24 08:56:18.507 DentalAsia[47301:60b] Progress is 0.340136
2014-04-24 08:56:18.764 DentalAsia[47301:60b] Progress is 0.343537
2014-04-24 08:56:19.041 DentalAsia[47301:60b] Progress is 0.346939
2014-04-24 08:56:19.210 DentalAsia[47301:60b] Progress is 0.350340
2014-04-24 08:56:19.549 DentalAsia[47301:60b] Progress is 0.353741
2014-04-24 08:56:19.714 DentalAsia[47301:60b] Progress is 0.357143
```

But for some reason my `UIProgressview` is not moving! 
Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks !

Comment: You should perform show progress on main thread

Comment: you have to update ui in main thread.

Comment: Is the completion block running on the main thread?  If so, you have some work to do.

Comment: @user3386109 how do I now if this is runnen on the main thread ?

Comment: Put an NSLog in viewDidLoad. Then compare the thread ID from that NSLog with the thread ID in the completion block NSLog.  The thread ID in the NSLogs you posted is [47301:60b], but that will change every time you run the program.

Comment: But I don't have a viewDidload. This is inside a custom uitableviewCell

Comment: Right, but put an NSLog in _any_ viewDidLoad. Since viewDidLoad always runs on the main thread, it will give you the main thread ID.

Comment: @user3386109 this is the NSLOg inside my ViewDidLoad 2014-04-24 09:18:43.031 DentalAsia[47702:60b] LOAD THREAD

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51322/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-user3386109)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you update the progress view on the main thread:

```
 -(void)calculatePie:(int)i{
    float progress = (100.0 / amountFiles) * i;
    float progress2 = progress / 100.0;
    NSLog(@"Progress is %f",progress2);

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [progressView setProgress:progress2 animated:YES];
    });
  }
```

Comment: It still keeps the same? The progressview is inside a custom cell. And the code above is also inside the custom class of the custom cell? Maybe there is the problem ?

Comment: Just to be on the save side; progressView is not nil right? ;-)